# Cognitive Services Speaker Recognition - set Phrase

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have an UWP application (with NuGet package Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeakerRecognition) where I can set enrollment and recognize a speaker.

The question is how to set enrollment phrase. Currently speaker could use only first one "I am going to make him an offer he cannot refuse"

As I can see on [example](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api) phrase could be set.
But as I can see in documentation - I can get only [list of phrases](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5652c0801984551c3859634d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have understand it is possible to use only one phrase for profile.

So, first phrase could be chosen by speaker (it could be any phrase from list).
But couldn't be changed to another later (only could be possible to clear all enrollments with ResetEnrollmentsAsync)

Answer (score 1):

You currently cannot use custom phrase list for enrollment.  You would send an audio file using "Verification Profile - Create Enrollment".  The following phrases can be used for enrollment.

"I am going to make him an offer he cannot refuse"

"Houston we have had a problem"

"My voice is my passport verify me"

"Apple juice tastes funny after toothpaste"

"You can get in without your password"

"You can activate security system now"

"My voice is stronger than passwords"

"My password is not your business"

"my name is unknown to you"

"be yourself everyone else is already taken"